# Retrieiving data from query in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query of elastic search. I have made connection to the Elastic Search Service. Is there any function to which I can pass that query to get the data ?

```
curl -XGET '{"server":"","headers":{"":"","":"::9::pKkwo1aE3/u02VLD3Kf/docRx/iqJ0fw=="},"port":"43","protocol":"https:","host":""}/contact_index-2015' -d '{
  "facets": {
    "terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ABC",
        "size": 50,
        "order": "count",
        "exclude": []
      },
      "facet_filter": {
        "fquery": {
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "query_string": {
                        "query": "*",
                        "_name": "Contact Information"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                         "@timestamp": {
                          "from": 143,
                          "to": 149
                         }
                       }
                     }
                   ]
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}'
```

For instance, this is the query. Is there a built-in function to which this query can be passed and a JSON List can be received as the output ?  I am using JAVA

Comment: You forgot to tell us what client technology you're using? PHP, JS, ...?

Comment: @Val : I am using java

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch comes with its inbuilt JAVA API using which you can form your desired queries and get the results in JSON format. Which can be parsed to whatever type you need using Jackson Library

Here is the Link for documentation of  [ElasticSearch Java API 5.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-term-level-queries.html)

You can Explore these pages get the information to form the desired query.